# How to redirect after submitting form

Tags: javascript, sveltekit

I'm new to Javascript and Svelte and I'm trying to redirect after submitting a form.
I've tried many things, but the goto function seems to be the only thing that even tries to load the redirected page. Unfortunately I get the following error message. Why does it happen?

> 500 
> Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    import { goto } from '$app/navigation';

    let title;
    let description;
    let images;

    async function submitForm() {
        const dataArray = new FormData();
        dataArray.append("title", title);
        dataArray.append("description", description);
        dataArray.append("image", images[0]);

        const submit = await fetch("new.json", {
            method: "post",
            body: dataArray
        })

        const data = await submit.json();
        // do something with data

        goto("/");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: We have no way of knowing what the server is returning a 500 error. Look at the logs. Look at the HTML document it is returning (the thing which starts with `<` so isn't valid JSON). Look at the Network tab in the browser's developer tools. Look at the server-side code that handles the URL you are requesting. Make sure that the URL you are requesting is the correct URL.

Comment: Please read the tag [tag:redirect] carefully. Having client-side code `goto("/")` is not a redirect. Also note that what you want to do **after** the thing that causes the error isn't your problem. Focus your question on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com"; to get redirect

```js
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use location.replace("/"); on success

Comment: or `location.assign`